# JSON returning NULL in Perl

Tags: json, perl

When trying to run my perl script via `cmd` prompt my `json` string is returning `[]`  I have read other posts, and fixed my database to be `utf8` and the error still persists.  I have tried two didfferent way to encode my perl string the first was `$json = encode_json @temp_array` which returns this error `hash- or arrayref expected (not a simple scalar, use allow_nonref to allow this`  However, when I use this line `$json_text = $json->encode(@temp_array)` I just get `[]`

Here is my perl:

```
my $json_text;
my $json = JSON->new->utf8;
my @temp_array =[];
my $temp_array;
while (@data = $query_handle->fetchrow_array()) 
    {
    my %json_hash = ();
    my $hash_ref;
    %json_hash = (
                "User ID" => $data[0],
                "Status" => $data[1],
                "Last Password Reset" => $data[2],
                "Reset Needed" => $data[3]
                );
    $hash_ref = \%json_hash;
    push (@temp_array, $hash_ref);
    }   

print $json = encode_json @temp_array . "\n";   #encode with error
print $json_text = $json->encode(@temp_array) . "\n"; #encode with []
print $cgi->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
print $json_text; #Prints []
```

So in my own testing, via the `cmd prompt` I know the while is retrieving the data from my db correctly and is building a hash, which I am assuming is correct.

Is it the fact I am pushing my hash reference to the array instead of the hash itself?  Once I get this string built correctly, I will be calling it to an html via `jquery`

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON expects references:

```
print $json = encode_json(\@temp_array) . "\n";   
print $json_text = $json->encode(\@temp_array) . "\n";
```

Edit: Unless you enable [allow_nonref](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm#allow_nonref).

Another edit: This line is wrong--

```
my @temp_array =[]; ## should be my @temp_array = ();
```

and this line overwrites the $json variable:

```
print $json = encode_json @temp_array . "\n"; ## the next line in your script shouldn't work
```

Last edit - untested:

```
my $json = JSON->new->utf8;
my @temp_array;
while (my @data = $query_handle->fetchrow_array()) {
    my %json_hash = (
            "User ID" => $data[0],
            "Status" => $data[1],
            "Last Password Reset" => $data[2],
            "Reset Needed" => $data[3]
    );
    push (@temp_array, \%json_hash);
}   

print $json->encode(\@temp_array) . "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you.  Did find an issue with your "untested" code example:
`print encode_json \@temp_array . "\n";` still give me the error
1print $json->encode(\@temp_array) . "\n";` outputs EXACTLY what I am expecting!!  THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Thanks. I removed the line. I suspect that I should have added `()` on that line.